# DHCP over UDP sending question

Tags: c++, udp, dhcp

I am trying to make a simple DHCP client. It should send a message to DHCP server (already have this) receive a message back and parse it.
I have created a struct

```
struct dhcp_msg{
 _int8 op;  //opcode
 _int8 htype; //hardware type
 _int8 haddr; //hardware adress
 _int8 hops;  //hop count

 _int32 tid;  //transaction id

 _int16 sec;  //seconds
 _int16 unused; //unused

 _int32 cipaddr;  //client ip
 _int32 yipaddr;  //your ip
 _int32 sipaddr;  //server ip
 _int32 gipaddr;  //gateway ip

 char chaddr[16]; //client hardware address
 char sname[64];  //server name
 char bname[128]; //boot file name

 _int8 mcookie[4];  //magic cookie
};
```

If I fill all fields with according data how to send this with sendto()? Should i parse it into char and send a pointer as sendto() requaries a pointer as a second parameter.

```
char *buffer;
...?
sendto(socketC, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (SOCKADDR *)&servAddr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
```

How to send this message?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you must say to your compiler not to add any paddings into structures. And then you can do:

```
struct dhcp_msg my_msg;
// Fill my_msg
sendto(socket, (void *) &my_msg, ...)
```

**UPDATE**

In Linux and Windows `sendto` function are a bit different as we figured out in comments to this answer. So we should use `(void *)` and `(char *)` conversion for Linux and Windows respectively.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto

About endianess: you should be also careful about it. But it should fork fine for all x86 CPUs. The only "wrong" endian style system I've ever used was a super computer based on IBM Power6.

Comment: @Elalfer: it's not necessary to cast to void*; conversion is implicit.

Comment: You also need to be careful about endianness.

Comment: I do not see any problems about strict casting in this case. Usually I prefer to define it myself.

Comment: @Martin, C++ does not allow implicit casts to/from `void*` - this is one of the subtle cases where C++ fails to be a strict superset of C.

Comment: @Elalfer: it hurts readability. You have side-stepped that problem with the "..." omission of additional parameters somewhat.

Comment: In this particular example I wanted to show that in `sendto` buffer parameter is not an `char *` but `void *`

Comment: @bdonlan: Why do you say that? Implicit conversion *to* `void*` works just fine in C++. It's conversion *from* `void*` where C++ deviates from C, however, this is irrelevant for the issue at hand.

Comment: @Elalfer, judging from the error message the OP gave, his compiler is expecting `const char *` rather than `void *`.

Comment: his compiler?!? It is not compiler dependent. It is defined in the POSIX standard that it must be `void *`!

Comment: maybe his compiler / OS api violates POSIX? `;)`

Comment: i get the same error. argument type (void *) is incompatible with parameter type of const char *

Comment: visual studio 2010 and windows 7

Comment: ohhh Microsoft. They are violates everything :)

Comment: @Elalfer Regarding the edit: in linux implicit cast to `void*` is sufficient. So no explicit cast is *needed*, `&msg` works just fine.

Comment: @gemexas, could you try to compile test source from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700633/dhcp-over-udp-sending-question/4700848#4700848

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the address of the buffer to `sendto`. No matter what type it will have - what really matters for `sendto` is the bytes there.

```
struct dhcp_msg msg;
// fill in all fields...
sendto(socketC, &msg, sizeof(struct dhcp_msg), ...);
```

The length of your message will be `sizeof(struct dhcp_msg)`.

And don't forget that your compiler may add [padding bytes](http://clinuxpro.com/Cprogramming/structurepadding.php) to the struct, so its size may become bigger than you expect.

Comment: you need to be careful with structures padding

Comment: that was my first idea, but i get - error C2664: 'sendto' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'dhcp_msg *' to 'const char *'

Comment: @gemexas Hmm. Then try explicit typecasting, `(void*)msg`.

Comment: @gemexas that can't be. Any pointer must be castable to `void*`. Are you compiling with C++ compiler? Tried `static_cast<void*>`?

Comment: static_cast gives me invalid type conversion error. btw i am using visaul studio 2010 and windows 7. might be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start a new answer, as others have too much comments which are hard to dig in.

The problem which OP really has is a pointer type conversion error: MSVC refuses to pass `struct dhcp_msg*` as a `const char*` argument, and no explicit conversions help.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

struct test {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    struct test t;
    t.a = 3;
    t.b = 5;
    send(1, &t, sizeof(struct test), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This source is not intended to be run, but it *compiles* fine with my GCC 4.4.5 (as well as `void*` and `char*` typecasting variants).

Ok, problem solved by doing typecasting carefully.

Answer (score -2):

cast your struct dhcp_msg into a char*